# How to append element to popup windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append more data and style my table inside my popup window.

I have

```
 var popup = window.open("popup.html", "popup","width=800","height=600");
     popup.document.write(
     "<table id='dataTable'>"+
      "<tr><th>test1</th><th>test2</th><th>test3<th></th>test4</th><th>test5</th></tr>" +
      "</table>");

ajax callback data
    codes....
```

How to append the data and style my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$("#dataTable",popup.document)` to get your table in popup window:

```
var popup = window.open("popup.html", "popup","width=800","height=600");
     popup.document.write(
     "<table id='dataTable'>"+
     "<tr><th>test1</th><th>test2</th><th>test3<th></th>test4</th><th>test5</th></tr>" +
     "</table>");

$("#dataTable",popup.document)
     .css("border","1px solid red") // append CSS
     .append("<tr><td>append</td></tr>"); //append HTML
```

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SFKPp/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dataTable').append(<your html>);
$('#dataTable').css({'style1':'value1', 'style2':'value2'});
```